# Example of a principal prime ideal containing a proper prime non-zero ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, unique-factorization-domains

It is true that if $A$ is UFD and $I=\left\langle p \right\rangle$ is a principal prime ideal, it does not exist a proper prime non-zero ideal contained in $I$, but this property does not hold for general rings (commutative rings with 1). I would appreciate some examples, that is, a ring $A$ and prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}, \left\langle p \right\rangle$ such that 
\begin{equation}
0 \subsetneq \mathfrak{p} \subsetneq \left\langle p \right\rangle
\end{equation}